# Open visible window from invisible BAT window on startup

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, scheduled-tasks, executable

I'm writing this little program that prevents scheduled tasks from being added into the system without user's knowledge https://github.com/DVLP/Unscheduler

Some background about how the program works

1. install.bat creates a snapshot of current scheduled tasks is being recorded and a new task is being added check.bat to run on each logon
2. Every time check.bat runs it fetches list of all scheduled tasks and compares it with snapshot
3. When a task is not in snapshot its being displayed on the list
4. Now the user can press a number to delete any new entry
5. When happy, the user presses "S" to save a new snapshot

That's all

It's all working fine on my computer but in step **2** on each logon a window appears even if no entries are present.

Finally the actual question:

How do I first run it in a hidden way and only display the window (or re-run it visible) when there are new entries detected?

Currently the window is either - running as System - always invisible
OR running as user - always visible

I know about "runas" but that requires prompting for user password. Everything now works fine without prompting for password so prompting even once during install.bat is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround by creating two tasks

-FirstTask is running invisible as System on every logon

-SecondTask is created as user's task to run only once - in 50 years(never, basically only there to be triggered manually)

-When the first task detects new entries it's using `schtasks /run /ts SecondTask` to run the second task with visible window allowing user interaction